# why there is so no convergence although you can see that the agent is learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

Recently i have been tackling a problem with reinforcement learning (im very new in the field). The problem is simple. we have a matrix of size NxN with all elements equal to zero. the goal is for the agent to change all values to 1. I can see that the agent is learning in course of time, but whatever i do, there is a lot of noise in my output graph and i don't see convergence! on the other hand slight changes in hyper parameters can ruin the learning process for me! from learning to not learning at all!

for instance i used a 5x5 matrix. the epsilon function for exploration/exploitation trade off is as follows:

```
egreedy = 0.9
egreedy_final = 0.02
egreedy_decay = 5000

def calculate_epsilon(steps_done):
epsilon = egreedy_final + (egreedy - egreedy_final) * \
          math.exp(-1 * steps_done / egreedy_decay)

return epsilon
```

The epsilon function decreases the randomness in each time step (not episode). i set 5000 episodes and each episode has 50 time steps. Furthermore i am using experience replay with target net, one hidden layer each. these are my hyper parameters:

```
learning_rate = 0.01
num_episodes = 5000
gamma = 0.8
max_time_steps = 50


hidden_layer1 = 64

replay_mem_size = 1000000
batch_size = 32

update_target_frequency = 5000

egreedy = 0.9
egreedy_final = 0.02
egreedy_decay = 5000
```

And this is the sum of rewards per episode with respect to number of episodes:
[image]

it can be seen that there is learning but there are two problems. first, the maximum reward that the agent can get per episode is 25 but here we can see maximum it got is 20.

by changing the number of explorations per episode to 100 (4x the number of pixels) i get to 25 but still i don't see any convergence and the solution is not stable:
[image]

as i tried to increase the number of episodes, i didn't see any better result. seems one thing which really affects the result is the number of explorations per episode. but it doesn't follow a linear pass. For instance if i have a 3x3 matrix (9 pixels), 18 time steps are enough for each episode (which is 2x number of pixels). for 5x5, 100 time steps work (i also put 200 but results didnt change much), but my actual problem is way more complex! both in goal configuration and in size (minimum 20x20 matrix) and it is way way more time consuming, because in each time step a complex simulation is being run in the background! Hence, just playing around with the parameters for that problem is almost impossible for me given the time i have!

Is there a general way to optimize the hyper parameters without being forced to examine everything over and over again? like is there a kind of recipe? why i don't see convergence here? (i have used way more number of episodes and still i have the problem!) how can i solve this convergence problem?

Thanks a lot! If you need more information about my code, i can also put it here!